# update only if row exists (IF THEN)

Tags: postgresql, sql-update

I'm looking to run the follow query:

```
UPDATE
    creator.contacts
SET
    status = 'accepted'
WHERE
    (
        account_id = $1
        AND
        contact_id = $2
    )
    OR
    (
        account_id = $2
        AND
        contact_id = $1
    )
```

But only on a certain condition, which I query using the following:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    creator.contacts
WHERE
    account_id = $1
    AND
    status = 'pending'
```

Is it possible to combine this into one query?

Comment: No, in general it is not possible to do a select and update at the same time.

Comment: Unrelated, but: your `where` clause can be simplified to `where (account_id, contact_id) in ( ($1, $2), ($2,$1))`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name cool, never knew that, does definitely simplify things then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add that condition to your `WHERE` clause as an `EXISTS` test. Note that you need to add `()` around your existing `WHERE` clause to ensure correct order of evaluation of the logical operators:

```
UPDATE
    creator.contacts
SET
    status = 'accepted'
WHERE
    ((
        account_id = $1
        AND
        contact_id = $2
    )
    OR
    (
        account_id = $2
        AND
        contact_id = $1
    ))
    AND
        EXISTS (SELECT * 
                FROM  creator.contacts
                WHERE
                   account_id = $1
                AND
                   status = 'pending')
```

Comment: cool, gives me no errors, I'll have to try this out. I'm hoping performance is better than two queries.

Comment: @A.Lau how did you go? Was it an improvement?

Comment: Yeah, does as expected